# How to scale a signal to get desired variance

Tags: scaling

I am new to dsp, and I'd really appricate it if someone please help me with this problem. I guess it's a basic simple question, but I cannot get it write. Here is the question:

The variance of a random signal generated using MATLAB command randn is approximately 1. We need a random signal with variance 0.01. With which factor you need to scale the signal?

With amplitude? Like we need to multiple the amplitude of the signal by 0.1?

Comment: Assuming you want a normal independent RV   sqrt(var)*randn.

Comment: I need to scale the signal with this  sqrt(var)*randn? Why?

Comment: Because it answered the question you asked.  Google "standardizing a random variable" and work backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a practical setting to adjust the variance (thereof the power) of a random process, you could use the following to get what you want.

Let the variance of a given RV $X$ be $$\text{Var}\{X\} =  \sigma_X^2 $$

Then the following transform $$ Y = K X $$ ($K$ being a scalar) will define a RV $Y$ with a variance given by

$$\text{Var}\{Y\} = \text{Var}\{ K X\}  = K^2 \text{Var}\{ X\} = K^2 \sigma_X^2 = \sigma_Y^2$$

So, given a variance of $\sigma_X^2$ and a desired variance of $\sigma_Y^2$, you shall compute the necessary gain $K$ as

$$ K = \frac{ \sigma_Y }{\sigma_X} $$

Answer (score 1):

standardizing a Normal random variable $x$
$$ 
\frac{x -m}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
so if $y$ is a random variable that is Normal with mean zero, with standard deviation $1$, 
$$
\sqrt{\sigma^2}y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)
$$
This standardization actually works for more than just Normal Distributions.